# Supported Device - Android

Tags: android

I am uploading an app to the playstore and it is showing 
Supported devices:
5569
Unsupported devices:
9628

Can someone please confirm me the total supported devices for:
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26

I am not using any hardware dependent features in the app.

How can increase these numbers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The lower an Android API version becomes, the more devices it supports.  Thus, if the desire is to increase the amount of supported devices, it is best to decrease the API version, so long as the functionality you have already created is not impeded.

Here is [data](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) based on the number of devices that support each API as of January 8th, 2018:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Android version is not the only condition, maybe your application uses devices such as GPS, accelerometers, sensors, telephony, minimal screen resolution etc that not all Android devices have/support them.

In general, more permissions declared in your app manifest means less compatible devices.

Comment: My app only uses GPS and Telephony .

Comment: Most tablets do not have telephony and many do not have GPS, the same thing happens with other android devices that are neither phone nor tablet, such as televisions, watches, car screens, etc.